# select rows with 'where' that not match all condition

Tags: postgresql

I need to create a statement that select all row that mach 3 conditions or more.
This statement will be used by a high-performance JS function.
A record have some informations: `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, `qux` and `fum`.
I thought of 2 ways to do that and I chose the one that seems to me the best but maybe there is better ?

#### The first one (the best I think)

1. The db run a statement where the `where` clause match 3 conditions or more

   > I mean that for example the DB must returns all the rows where 3 fields or more match.
   >   Below there is an example of the query, is there a way do it ? I think this one is pretty ugly... And if I need to add some informations...
2. If more than 1 record the JS script determine the good one (iterate over the results)

Query example :

```sql
select * from MyTable
    where (foo='foo1' and bar='bar1' and baz='baz1')
    or    (foo='foo1' and bar='bar1' and qux='qux1')
    or    (foo='foo1' and bar='bar1' and fum='fum1')
    or    (bar='bar1' and baz='baz1' and qux='qux1')
    or    (bar='bar1' and baz='baz1' and fum='fum1')
    [other or for 3 conditions match ...]
    or    (foo='foo1' and bar='bar1' and baz='baz1' and qux='qux1')
    or    (foo='foo1' and bar='bar1' and baz='baz1' and fum='fum1')
    or    (foo='foo1' and bar='bar1' and qux='qux1' and fum='fum1')
    [other or for 4 conditions match ...]
    or    (foo='foo1' and bar='bar1' and baz='baz1' and qux='qux1' and fum='fum1') /* 5 conditions match */
```

#### The other one  (surely the worst I think) :

1. DB return all rows that match at one condition
2. then the JS script determine the good one by iterating over all the results

Query example :

```sql
select * from MyTable
    where foo='foo1' or bar='baz1' or baz='baz1' or qux='qux1'
```

Do you agree that the first one gives the best performance? If yes is there a better query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=03dba3af880e09392ec38945fce5b3f1)

```
SELECT
    t.*
FROM mytable t
WHERE     
    (foo IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 'foo1')::int + 
    (bar IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 'bar1')::int + 
    (baz IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 'baz1')::int + 
    (qux IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 'qux1')::int + 
    (fum IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 'fum1')::int >= 3
```

`IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` checks for equality and considers `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

You can check below query

```
select * from
(
select  a.*,  
case when foo='foo1' then 1 else 0 end + 
case when bar='baz1' then 1 else 0 end + 
case when baz='baz1' then 1 else 0 end + 
case when qux='qux1' then 1 else 0 end + 
case when fum='fum1' then 1 else 0 end as total
    from MyTable a 
        where foo='foo1' or bar='baz1' or baz='baz1' or qux='qux1' or fum = 'fum1'
    ) as a
    where total>=3;
```